# Windows Forms Application Basics: Resizing and Relocation of controls upon Changing to Full Screen

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, forms

This is quite a simple question, so hopefully I don't over explain here.  I would like to make my forms application have controls (buttons, DataViewGrids, etc) that automatically relocate themselves upon changing the window to full screen.  (Any C# answer is also welcome although I posted VB.net code below).

I tried anchoring my controls to the proper locations, as well as messing around with all of the various options for AutoSize but surprisingly, this didn't work.

I set up my application by making a single main Form, and then one main Panel on that form, and then encapsulating all of the functionality of the different parts of the application in UserControls.  I dynamically show/hide the UserControls on the Panel as needed throughout the navigation of the application.

For example, if the user clicks on the "Move data to Excel!" button, we navigate there by hiding the previously shown UserControl on the Panel, and show DataToExcel.vb in it's place.  Here is DataToExcel.vb:

```
Public Class DataToExcel
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
Dim db As theDataContext = New theDataContext()

Private Sub ToExcel_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Location on screen stuff:  This is probably what I need to change!
    MainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    MainForm.MainPanel.AutoSize = True
    MainForm.MainPanel.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly
End Sub

Private Sub BackButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackButton.Click
    Dim IntroductionForm = New Introduction
    MainForm.MainPanel.Controls.Clear()
    MainForm.MainPanel.Controls.Add(IntroductionForm)
    MainForm.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(837, 588)
    MainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal '<-- Go back to non-fullscreen.
    IntroductionForm.Show()
End Sub

' ...Other functions and subs related to the functionality of DataToExcel...

End Class
```

For example, I have a "Back" button which is anchored to the Bottom Left of this UserControl.  However, upon changing to full screen, this button remains in the same place it was before, and does not change it's location to the Bottom Left corner of the app.  This results in an ugly, non-dynamic look.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? (I noticed that in [another one of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146387/windows-forms-object-reference-not-set-error-upon-accessing-a-forms-properties) you also tagged a VB.NET/Winforms question with C#. Please use only appropriate tags.)

Comment: You have 2 choices, use Anchors and Docking or do it manually in code. Based on the code you supplied, you did not try docking.

Comment: Docking does not work either.  I am thinking that I may have to simply manually create a resizing function depending on how they resize the application.  If the back button's location was 200,200, and they resize the form by adding 50,50 in overall size, then the new button location is 150, 250.  Seems complicated for such a simple thing but it should work...

Comment: My guess is that your button docks to the user control just fine, but your user control is not docked to the window. When your window changes size, your user control remains in the same spot, does not change size, so your button does not change either.

Answer (score 1):

Anchoring should work for this but you have to keep in mind where you want the control to relocate to when resizing.

Consider a form with the following code:

```
    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 227);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 227);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "button2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
```

When I drag the lower left corner around, button2 maintains its position relative to the right and bottom of the screen (this includes maximizing the form). However, button1 appears to not move. But if I drag the top left corner the opposite is true.

Will this not work for you?

Comment: Hi Chuck, thank you for the reply.  I will try this now, actually!

Comment: If you want the control to expand (which you would commonly want with a panel but probably not for a button) then you will want to anchor it on three or all four sides. I didn't initially find this intuitive but once I fiddled with it some, it makes sense now.

Comment: Hi @Musicode, if this helped you would you mind marking this as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I still never figured this out, actually.  I can't mark this as the answer because I have tried a similar strategy and I couldn't get it to work.